# is there a way I can use Color property in model to populate another property of model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have this model class BrandColors. I want to populate the property HexCode and RGBCode from the color. Is there any way to do that.

```
public class BrandColors :CSSItem
{   
    public Color color { get; set; }    
    public string RGBCode { get; set; }
    public string HexCode { get; set; }

    public BrandColors()
    {
        HexCode = color.Name.PadLeft(6, '0');
    }
   }
  }
```

I have another model where I will be populating it

```
    private void InitializeBrandColors()
    {
        BrandColors.Add(new BrandColors()
        {
            color = Color.FromArgb(0,0,51,0),            
        });
         BrandColors.Add(new BrandColors()
        {
            color = Color.FromArgb(0,82,72,53),
        });
      }
```

In the view I am able to access the properties of color object like

```
         @brandcolor.color.Name.PadLeft(6, '0')<br>
        RGB brandcolor.color.R,@brandcolor.color.G,@brandcolor.color.B
```

But I want to do something like accessing directly

```
     @brandcolor.HexCode
     @brandcolor.RGBCode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only actual backing data is the `color` property then make your other properties read-only calculated properties.  Something like this:

```
public class BrandColors :CSSItem
{   
    public Color color { get; set; }    
    public string HexCode
    {
        get { return color.Name.PadLeft(6, '0'); }
    }
    // something similar for RGBCode, however you calculate that
}
```

Basically you shouldn't try to duplicate information in multiple places.  Even if the information *presents* differently, the only actual piece of information is the `Color`.  Everything else is just a calculation based on that.  Keeping the same information in multiple places means keeping it synchronized, which escalates problems quickly.

After all, what would happen if anything ever invoked the `set` on `HexCode`?  Then the model would be in an invalid state.  With a calculated property that has only a `get` and no `set`, that can't happen.  Consuming code can only `set` the `color` property, and the other properties will automatically reflect that change.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it.I didn't think this way.